# Create groups by random assignment in python

Tags: python, pandas, distribution, uniform-distribution

I have a dataset with model scores in 3 categories (high, medium and low). The table looks like below:

```
| Score   |
| ------- |
| high    |
| high    |
| high    |
| low     |
| low     |
| low     |
| medium  |
| medium  |
| medium  |
```

I want to randomly assign these scores into 4 groups. `control`, `treatment 1`, `treatment 2`, `treatment 3`. `control` group should have 20% of the observations and the rest 80% has to be divided into the other 3 equal sized groups. However, i want the distribution of scores (high, medium and low) in each group to be the equal. How can i solve this using python?

PS: This is just a representation of the actual table, but it will have a lot more observations than this.

Comment: *i want the distribution of scores (high, medium and low) in each group to be the equal* this is not possible unless original `Score` types are evenly distributed.

Comment: Yes the score types will be evenly distributed. It is obtained from qcut() so it will be evenly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby.transform`:

```
cats = [ 'control', 'treatment 1', 'treatment 2', 'treatment 3']
probs = [.2, .8/3, .8/3, .8/3]


(df.groupby('Score')['Score']
   .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(cats, size=len(x), p=probs, replace=True)
)
```

Comment: This is great. But i want to add the groups as another column to the existing table.

Comment: Yes, `df['groups'] = what_provided`

Comment: Groupby is to ensure that the sampling happens within the group. If you remove it, there's no guarantee that the `cats` distribution are the same across the `Score` (although it likely is)

Comment: It is just giving me NaN values for the 'group' column.

Comment: oh, use `.transform` instead of `.apply`. Sorry

Comment: Worked perfectly well! Thanks a ton!